# How to define a default colour/font for use across multiple forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need a default colour and font in one common place in order to use it in multiple windows forms for a desktop application.

What is the best practice for this?

I am thinking of using the Application Settings to define them there but I want to make sure that this is the recommended way or if there is an alternative.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a base form and derive all of your forms from the base. The base form would have the properties set the way you'd like them to appear in all of your other forms.

Comment: Is it better to set the default colour and font in base form as you said instead of using the Application Settings? What are the pros and cons between the ways?

Comment: If you make it an application setting you would need to load it into every single form you create. You could make it an application setting and load it into your base form. The benefit of having it as a base form is that all you have to do is inherit from it in order to apply all of your changes.